# Applescript: move mouse cursor to 'currently selected item'?

Tags: macos, applescript, hotkeys

To give a specific example: I have a file highlighted in Finder inside a large directory. I want to invoke a right-click event on that item (no matter the current position of the cursor), so as to make a script that can essentially perform 'context menu' on the currently-selected Finder item.

Is it possible with Applescript to a. know what (and where) the currently-selected (highlighted) item is, and then b. move the mouse cursor over it (such as its position in the name column)?

Comment: What does the contextual menu item do? Perhaps there is another solution for this.

Comment: Oh, I know I can usually make an individual hotkey for various functions that are in the (e.g. Finder) context menu, but that's not the point: new functions will always crop up as I add new apps to OS X (that add context menu items) and the point is, in general, to be able to invoke the context menu instead of laboriously fashioning (and finding hotkey real estate for) a hotkey for every new function in the menu that I want to reach, when a simple general context menu hotkey will save time and work as a good 'one two' punch for most of what I'll want to do in it without using the mouse.

Comment: @user784142: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tool I built called MouseTools to do the things you asked. It can tell you the mouse coordinates, move the move to any coordinates, and perform right-clicks. There's example applescript code on the page to show you how to use it. You can find it [here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html). Good luck.

Comment: You built MouseTools? awesome, cos I'm using that for another script of my own already! But, what I need to do is to - in code - automatically read wherever on the screen the 'current selected item' is. MouseTools doesn't look like it can do that (but rather perform the second half of this process), would I be right? Cos the item is not in a fixed position; 'currently selected item' could mean literally anywhere on the screen and it changes dynamically with each instance.